# Accessing tapes at the Windows Server 2008 R2 with NTBackup backups

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, restore, tape, ntbackup, windows

Does anyone know any solution how to access tapes at the Windows Server 2008 R2, tapes written with NTBackup from earlier Windows versions ???

I appreciate free or low cost solution to access such tapes without necessity to install tape drive on second PC / Server with Windows 2000, XP, 2003, Vista system as Microsoft advices to Windows 7 / 2008 R2 users.

The key problem is Microsoft left developing and implementing Remote Storage Manager service starting from Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 editions. This service is no longer available in any way. Without that service, even having free Microsoft NT Backup Restore Utility - it is simply impossible to access tape device :-(

Comment: ^ That's because tape is (finally!) starting to lose ground as the premier media to backup to.

Answer (score 0):

Symantec BackupExec is able to restore NTBACKUP tapes - see the [Restore old Backup Exec tapes with NTbackup](https://serverfault.com/questions/230845/restore-old-backup-exec-tapes-with-ntbackup) question for more details. This would work on from at least BackupExec 2010 (the first BE version supported for Windows Server 2008 R2).